# Firebase firestore Pagination is returning duplicate results

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating a social feed where I want to have infinite scrolling, using firebase pagination but the query is returning the same each time even when I have a lot of different data in my firestore database.

This is my initial query:

```js
const getThreads = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const ref = firestore()
        .collection('Discover')
        .orderBy('rank', 'desc')
        .limit(10);

      let docSnaps = await ref.get();

      if (docSnaps.empty !== true) {
        let docData = docSnaps.docs.map(document => {
          return {
            data: document.data(),
            id: document.id,
          };
        });
        setLastVisible(docData[docData.length - 1].id);
        setThreads(docData); //Setting the data to display in UI
      }
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(e);
      Alert.alert(
        'Oops! Looks like something went wrong',
        'Please try again later',
        [{text: 'OK'}],
      );
    }
  };
```

As you can see each `post/thread` is being ordered by a `rank` field. And I'm setting the last visible as the `documentId` which is being used in the below query to get more `posts/threads`

```js
async function getMoreThreads() {
    try {
      console.log('Getting More threads');
      if (lastVisible !== null) {
        setRefreshing(true);
        const ref = firestore()
          .collection('Discover')
          .orderBy('rank', 'desc')
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(10);

        let docSnaps = await ref.get();

        if (docSnaps.empty !== true) {
          let docData = docSnaps.docs.map(document => {
            return {
              data: document.data(),
              id: document.id,
            };
          });
          console.log('DocData', docData.length);
          setLastVisible(docData[docData.length - 1].id);
          setThreads([...threads, ...docData]);
        }
        setRefreshing(false);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error getting more', e);
      Alert.alert(
        'Oops! Looks like somthing went wrong',
        'Please try again later',
        [{text: 'OK'}],
      );
    }
  }
```

My hypothesis of why this is happening is because I'm using `documentIds` to paginate and my  document Ids are numeric long integer strings like this 
`1002103360646823936,1259597720752291841, 974895869194571776, etc.`

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct. The field that you are using to paginate with `startAfter(...)` should match the field you are using in the `orderBy(...)` method - in this case, your `startAfter(...)` method is assuming that you are passing it a `rank` value.

You can pass in the `DocumentSnapshot` object in your `startAfter(...)` method instead:

```
const ref = firestore()
          .collection('Discover')
          .orderBy('rank', 'desc')
          .startAfter(documentSnapshot) // document snapshot of the last element
          .limit(10);
```